# Angular 2 AoT ngc does not generate any files

Tags: angular, compilation, angular-cli, tsc

When I run the offline compiler ngc on an Angular 2 RC5 vanilla project created by angular-cli, it does nothing.

Here's what I did

Setup:

```
ng new my-project
cd my-project
npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
```

Running the compiler

```
./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p ./src
```

The command output nothing and I did not see it generate a min.ngfactory.ts

What am I missing?

Comment: keep a track of [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11689)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and I solved this by down grade typescript to 2.0.2.

I found this on:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11689

Comment: I had the same issue with typescript 2.1.1, downgrading to 2.0.10 works as well.

Comment: Neither 2.0.2 or 2.0.10 work for me.  no ngfactory files

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: make sure you are using **Typescript 2.0.10**. Fix the version on your `package.json` file.

Discussion about it: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11689